# Proving controllability using eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, control-theory

Considering the pair $(A,b)$ where $A∈R^{n×n}$ and $b ∈R^{n×1}$ how can I show that if more than one linearly independent eigenvector can be associated with a single eigenvalue of $A$, then $(A,b)$ is uncontrollable.

My initial thought was to use the PBH test but the proof isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If more than one linearly independent eigenvector can be associated with a single eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ then the rank of $\lambda\,I-A$ drops by more than one, since those eigenvectors span the null space of $\lambda\,I-A$. However, when using the PBH test and that $b$ has only one column it can be noted that $b$ can at most increase the rank of $[\lambda\,I-A, b]$ by one, which implies rank-deficiency and thus uncontrollability.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/0XJHgLrcPeA&t=9m12s) contains some interesting additional information.